# Following Django official tutorial part 2, makemigrations issue, not getting Add field question to choice

Tags: python, django, model, migration

I got stuck on part 2 of the Django official tutorial while trying to make migrations after editing models.py.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models
I got only these two lines:
/mysite$ python manage.py makemigrations polls
Migrations for 'polls':
  polls/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Question
    - Create model Choice

Missing "- Add field question to choice" which later results in issues while I'm trying to add choices in Python shell.
I have been copying most of the code, nevertheless, my models.py is currently back to:

```
from Django.DB import models      

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Is there anything I could do wrong there to not get this "- Add field question to choice"?
Later when I was trying to add the first choice to that question console told me that:

```
>>> q = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> q
<Question: What's up?>
>>> q.choice_set.all()
<QuerySet []>
>>> q.choice_set.create(choice_text='Not much', votes=0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/rufus/.local/lib/python3.6/site-        
packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 519, in __repr__
return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)
  File "/home/rufus/mysite/polls/models.py", line 19, in __str__
return self.question_text
  AttributeError: 'Choice' object has no attribute 'question_text'
>>> q
<Question: What's up?>`
```

Should I edit models.py or something else is wrong here? Please help.

I tried changing models.py and doing makemigrations and migrate again but there were no changes in it.

Comment: The first is not an issue, just an old reference in the tutorial. The second is because you put `question_text` in the `__str__` method for Choice, instead of `choice_text`.

Comment: Thank you, I will be more careful in the future.